# Show every 10th result Drupal 7 Views

Tags: php, drupal-7, highcharts, drupal-views

I have Drupal 7 View. It contains 2249 results to be displayed on a graph. I am using the highcharts module to display that data. I have created a running total of the integer data with a global  math expression field. I wanted to keep the expression's total on the graph but limit the amount of results as they are overlapping each other and it looks really bad.

I am using aggregation to combine days that are similar but it seems at this point date granularity is not available with the date module in views.

Is there a way to do this views php filter and use a bit of php to do the math so it would work ?

I have a Global:PHP filter that has this in it but it's not doing anything right maybe someone has a tip to get it working properly -

```
if( $row->id % 10 == 0 ) return TRUE;
```

thanks

Comment: How your data looks like?

Comment: What specifically do you want to see what fields I am using ? thanks for your help

Comment: In case when you would like to add highcharts, you need series data, so I'd like to know how your data looks like ? Do you use JSON?

Comment: Its a drupal views query using the highcharts module 7.1x